# How to add one more pattern to my street-name regex?

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

I already have a [working example](https://regex101.com/r/WRd1jx/3) of a regex that matches most German street names. However, I recently learned, that the following patterns are possible as well:

- A 1
- K 7
- H 2
- P 1
- I 7
- E 7
- T 3
- Z 9

How can I build this pattern into my existing Python-regex?:

```
^(?:[^\W\d_]+\.?|\([^\W\d_]+\.?\))(?:[- '’](?:[^\W\d_]+\.?|\([^\W\d_]+\.?\)))*$
```

Comment: Like this? https://regex101.com/r/tepKwr/1 `^(?:[A-Z] \d+|[^\W\d_]+\.?|\([^\W\d_]+\.?\))(?:[- '’](?:[^\W\d_]+\.?|\([^\W\d_]+\.?\)))*$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add it with an `|`. It also seems that your pattern can be heavily simplified:

```regex
^(?:[A-Z] \d|[^\W\d_]{2,}\.?)(?:[- '’][^\W\d_]+\.?)*$
```

https://regex101.com/r/WRd1jx/7

Comment: Is it possible to add minimum value of characters? For example, I don't want to accept a value of "B" or "F" only.

Comment: Yes, you can just list all of the accepted characters individually in the character class, e.g. `[AEIKHPTZ]`

Comment: Can you please make an example (or even better: add to the regex above)? If I understand you correclty you just do sth. like ``| ^[a-zA-Z]``. Is this correct?

Comment: Oh sorry, you misunderstood me. I am fine with ``B 1`` and ``F 2``. I am not fine if the user just writes ``B``, ``F`` or any other single character. Thats what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

You could add matching an uppercase char followed by a space and 1+ digits to the alternation.

```
^(?:[A-Z] \d+|[^\W\d_]+\.?|\([^\W\d_]+\.?\))(?:[- '’](?:[^\W\d_]+\.?|\([^\W\d_]+\.?\)))*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tepKwr/1)